# orchard: include font awesome

Tags: orchardcms

How I can include font awesome to my module in admin (v.1.10.2.0)?

There is something similar like `Style.Require("jQueryUI_Orchard");` ?

Or I need add [Add awesome](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) to my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Orchard.Resources` provides a resource manifest for font awesome. Therefore add a reference to module `Orchard.Resources` and add `Style.Require("FontAwesome")` to a view to get font awesome included.